# Пагинация в PHP

Tags: php, pagination

Добрый день, коллеги!
У меня обычный код в PHP. Есть база в phpMyAdmin.  Внутри есть таблица "clients".
Количество записей, т.е клиентов, перевалило за 200 шт.
В браузере есть головной файл "clients.php", в котором через див:

```
      <script>
        $('#client_table').load('clients_table.php');
      </script>
```

загружается дочерний файл "clients_table.php" содержащий таблицу с данными из phpMyAdmin - "clients".
Записей все больше и больше, и список клиентов грузиться дольше и дольше.
Как сделать к загружаемому файлу "clients_table.php" - пагинацию? Чтобы записи отображались по 10 штук за раз с возможностью листания. Кол-во клиентов будет расти дальше! Везде искал, подходящего для себя не нашел.

Вот содержание файла "clients_table.php":

```
<?php
require_once('lib/database.php');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bishkek');

$db->orderBy("fio","asc");
$clients = $db->get('clients');
$i=1;
$search=@$_GET['search'];
$search_fio=@$_GET['search_fio'];

if($search_fio){
    $db->where("fio", "%$search_fio%", 'like');
    $clients = $db->get('clients');
}
elseif($search){
    $db->where("tel_no",$search);
    $clients = $db->get('clients');

}
?>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="catalog">
    <thead class="thead-default">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Ф.И.О.</th>
        <th>Номер телефона</th>
        <th>Дата регистрации</th>
        <th>Действия</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($clients as $visitor) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i++;?></td>
            <td><a href="view_client.php?cid=<?php echo $visitor['id']; ?>"><?php echo $visitor['fio']; ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $visitor['tel_no']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo date('G:i d/m/Y',$visitor['date_reg']); ?></td>
            </td><td align="center">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit_client" data-client_id="<?php echo $visitor['id'];?>" data-fio="<?php echo $visitor['fio'];?>" data-tel_no="<?php echo $visitor['tel_no'];?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_client">Править /
                <a href="process.php?client_id=<?php echo $visitor['id'];?>&link_target=del_client"> Удалить</a>  
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<style type="text/css">
    th {
        text-align: center;
    }
    td {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<script>
$(".edit_client").click(function() {
  var client_id=$(this).data('client_id');
  var fio=$(this).data('fio');
  var tel_no=$(this).data('tel_no');
   $('#client_id').val(client_id);
   $('#fio').val(fio);
   $('#tel_no').val(tel_no);
});
</script>
```

P.S. Внутри подключения к `database.php` идет подключение классов из `MysqliDb.php`, взятый из github'a. В следствии чего и используется `$db->`  Заранее спасибо! :-)

Comment: Уважайте людей, которые захотят вам помочь - отформатируйте код: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Тут такое дело, 200 записей это ничто! У вас индексы выставлены? Можете create statement для таблицы сюда скинуть. А так, постраничный вывод он конечно обязателен, но это больше забота о пользователе.

Comment: PS: https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php#L2224 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте необязательный `GET`-параметр для указания страницы, например, `page`. На основании этого параметра и количества записей, которые хотите видеть на странице, определяйте отступ для запроса к БД:

```
$offset = ($page-1) * $recordsPerPage; // если страницы нумеруем с 1
```

Количество страниц зависит от количества записей:

```
$pagesCount = ceil($recordsCount / $recordsPerPage);
```

Не забудьте указать лимит записей в запросе к БД равный `$recordsPerPage`.

Comment: https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php#L2224 :)

Comment: Интересно, за что новичку, т.е. мне, коллеги поставили -4 за этот вопрос?! Конечно, если человек опытен, то для него мой вопрос кажется несущественным, но для меня то любая задача - это покорение очередной вершины! Не хорошо это, НЕКРАСИВО!

Answer (score 0):

А не проще в sql запросе обрубать?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID > (page_id * limit) LIMIT limit
//page_id - берется из гет запроса, limit = задается какойнибудь константой в пхп к примеру
//кол-во страниц - entries_count / limit
```

Comment: А если удалить пару записей на странице?

Answer (score 0):

- Правильный ответ!
- Всем привет! После долгих проб и ошибок было найдено хорошее видео с пагинацией для тех у кого обычные функции и массивы.
- Я его переделал под свое ООП.

1) Вот оригинал (со ссылкой на видео в youtube):

```
<?php
// Line by line explanation : youtube.com/watch?v=T2QFNu_mivw
include_once("mysqli_connection.php");
// This first query is just to get the total count of rows
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM testimonials WHERE approved='1'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
// Here we have the total row count
$rows = $row[0];
// This is the number of results we want displayed per page
$page_rows = 10;
// This tells us the page number of our last page
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
// This makes sure $last cannot be less than 1
if($last < 1){
    $last = 1;
}
// Establish the $pagenum variable
$pagenum = 1;
// Get pagenum from URL vars if it is present, else it is = 1
if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
}
// This makes sure the page number isn't below 1, or more than our $last page
if ($pagenum < 1) { 
    $pagenum = 1; 
} else if ($pagenum > $last) { 
    $pagenum = $last; 
}
// This sets the range of rows to query for the chosen $pagenum
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
// This is your query again, it is for grabbing just one page worth of rows by applying $limit
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, datemade FROM testimonials WHERE approved='1' ORDER BY id DESC $limit";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
// This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
$textline1 = "Testimonials (<b>$rows</b>)";
$textline2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";
// Establish the $paginationCtrls variable
$paginationCtrls = '';
// If there is more than 1 page worth of results
if($last != 1){
    /* First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to 
       the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we
       generate links to the first page, and to the previous page. */
    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
        // Render clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target page number
        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
                $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
            }
        }
    }
    // Render the target page number, but without it being a link
    $paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';
    // Render clickable number links that should appear on the right of the target page number
    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
        if($i >= $pagenum+4){
            break;
        }
    }
    // This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the "Next"
    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a> ';
    }
}
$list = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    $firstname = $row["firstname"];
    $lastname = $row["lastname"];
    $datemade = $row["datemade"];
    $datemade = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($datemade));
    $list .= '<p><a href="testimonial.php?id='.$id.'">'.$firstname.' '.$lastname.' Testimonial</a> - Click the link to view this testimonial<br>Written '.$datemade.'</p>';
}
// Close your database connection
mysqli_close($db_conx);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{ font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
div#pagination_controls{font-size:21px;}
div#pagination_controls > a{ color:#06F; }
div#pagination_controls > a:visited{ color:#06F; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <h2><?php echo $textline1; ?> Paged</h2>
  <p><?php echo $textline2; ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $list; ?></p>
  <div id="pagination_controls"><?php echo $paginationCtrls; ?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

2) А вот мой работающий вариант.
а) Для этого в моем классе https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php#L2224 
пришлось поменять пару значений:

- функцию paginate, т.к. там нужно вытащить не одно, а два значения:

`public function paginate ($table, $page, $fields = null){
      $offset = $this->pageLimit * ($page - 1);
      $res = $this->withTotalCount()->get ($table, Array ($offset, $this->pageLimit), $fields);
     $dg = $this->totalPages = ceil($this->totalCount / $this->pageLimit);
            return [    "res" => $res,
                        "last" => $dg
                    ];
}`

- и переменную $pageLimit наверху. Его выставляешь так, сколько надо записей на 1 страницу.

б) Т.к. у меня таблица выходит во втором вложенном файле, то поэтому приходится передавать 
GET запрос на главный файл, а оттуда грузить нужный файл опять же с GET запросом.
Если у Вас 1 файл, то Вам не следует менять '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'

в) для вывода красивых кнопок в пагинации, не забудьте подключить БУТСТРАП
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Главный файл "clients.php":

```
<?php 
$pn = @$_GET['pn'];
if($pn == ""){
    $pn = 1;
} 
?>
<div>$('#client_table').load('clients_table.php?pn=<?php echo $pn; ?>');</div>
```

Вложенный файл "clients_table.php":

```
<?php
require_once('database.php'); // внутри подключение к MysqliDb.php

$pagenum = 1;

$res = $db->paginate('clients', $pagenum);
$last = $res['last'];


if($last < 1){
    $last = 1;
}

if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
}

if ($pagenum < 1) {
    $pagenum = 1; 
}else if($pagenum > $last){
    $pagenum = $last; 
}

$db->orderBy("fio","asc");
$res = $db->paginate('clients', $pagenum);
$clients = $res['res'];

$g=1;

$textline = "Страница <b>$pagenum</b> из <b>$last</b>";

$paginationCtrls = '';

if($last != 1){

    if ($pagenum > 3) {

        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="clients.php?pn=1" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><b><< </b></a> &nbsp;';
    }   
    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="clients.php?pn='.$previous.'" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><b>< </b></a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';

        for($i = $pagenum-2; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
                $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="clients.php?pn='.$i.'" class="btn btn-default" role="button">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
            }
        }
    }

    $paginationCtrls .= '<p color:black; class="btn btn-default" role="button"><b>'.$pagenum.'</b></p>&nbsp; ';

    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="clients.php?pn='.$i.'" class="btn btn-default" role="button">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
        if($i >= $pagenum+2){
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="clients.php?pn='.$next.'" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><b>>&nbsp;</b></a> ';
    }
        if ($pagenum < $last-2) {

        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="clients.php?pn='.$last.'" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><b> >></b></a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
    }
}
?>
<center>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="catalog">
    <thead class="thead-default">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Ф.И.О.</th>
        <th>Номер телефона</th>
        <th>Дата регистрации</th>
        <th>Действия</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($clients as $visitor) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $g++;?></td>
            <td><a href="view_client.php?cid=<?php echo $visitor['id']; ?>"><?php echo $visitor['fio']; ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $visitor['tel_no']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo date('G:i d/m/Y',$visitor['date_reg']); ?></td>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit_client" data-client_id="<?php echo $visitor['id'];?>" data-fio="<?php echo $visitor['fio'];?>" data-tel_no="<?php echo $visitor['tel_no'];?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_client">Править /
                <a href="process.php?client_id=<?php echo $visitor['id'];?>&link_target=del_client"> Удалить</a>  
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</center>

<div id="pagination_controls"><?php echo $paginationCtrls; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $textline; ?></div>

<style type="text/css">
    th {
        text-align: center;
    }
    td {
        text-align: center;
    }
div#pagination_controls{font-size:15px;}
div#pagination_controls > a{ color:#06F; }
div#pagination_controls > a{ text-decoration:none; }
div#pagination_controls > a:visited{ color:#06F; }
</style>
<script>
$(".edit_client").click(function() {
  var client_id=$(this).data('client_id');
  var fio=$(this).data('fio');
  var tel_no=$(this).data('tel_no');
   $('#client_id').val(client_id);
   $('#fio').val(fio);
   $('#tel_no').val(tel_no);
});
</script>
```

УСПЕХОВ ВСЕМ!!!